# Zend stack order of plugins assistance

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-plugin

I have several plugins, and I'm trying to figure out the order they should be applied in. Here they are:

- Acl and Authentication
- Custom ErrorHandler to use an errocontroller within a module
- Internationalization plugin
- View setup
- Area Setup (sets the area (frontend, backend, or install) so i can access it and use it for logic assistance throughout my application)
- Maintenance plugin (just reroutes the request to a maintenance page)

In what order would you put these?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Seems to me that each of these plugins would pretty much be applied at specific points in the bootstrap/dispatch loop.

Comment: right, and i'm trying to figure out whats the best ordering for registering these plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into responsibilities ...

Required to run:

- view setup

System behaviour:

- error reporting
- i18n

Application behaviour:

- acl

Nice to have:

- area setup (not sure what this is)
- maintenance redirect